# Работа с двумя представлениями в xCode

Tags: xcode, ios

У меня есть первый класс, вот эго интерфейс:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    UILabel *label1Outlet;
}
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label1Outlet;
@end
```

Есть второй класс , его интерфейс:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController {
    UILabel *label2Outlet;
}
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label2Outlet;
@end
```

Я во втором классе приравниваю значение метки к значению метки которая в первом классе (для этого создаю экземпляр первого класса):

```
ViewController *obj1=[[ViewController alloc] init];
    self.label2Outlet.text=obj1.label1Outlet.text;
```

Но у меня почему-то не работает. Вторая метка выходит пустая, т.е. он не видит obj1.label1Outlet.text. 
В чем дело?

Вот сам проект http://dfiles.ru/files/e74ppu5ex

Comment: @synthesize присутствует в обоих классах

Comment: а что будет, если перед присваиванием вывести NSLog(@"%@", obj1.label1Outlet.text); ?
Это, конечно, наивное предположение, но, может, его нету даже в obj1?
Если Вы не устанавливаете его в init-e, то ему неоткуда взяться.

Comment: Вывело пустоту null. label1Outlet есть в первом классе, но второй его не видит. Я недавно стал изучать програминг под ios  и немогу разобраться почему так

Comment: Что написано в методе [[ViewController alloc] init]?

Comment: Кроме @synthesize label1Outlet; я ничего в реализацию класса не добавлял (я привязал к этому классу метку, а в сторибоард прописал текст в метку).

Comment: а где Вы устанавливаете значение obj1.label1Outlet.text? Видимо, Вы пытаетесь ее считать до того, как она устанавливается.

Comment: Значение obj1.label1Outlet.text это текст в метке, который я прописал в сторибоард

Comment: Обновил свой ответ.

Comment: Предлагаю вам сделать zip из своего проекта и прислать на него сюда ссылку. Вам гарантированно придёт правильный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала попробуйте проверить что у вас вообще это выполняется

```
ViewController *obj1 = [[ViewController alloc] init];
self.label2Outlet.text = @"Hello";
```

Скорее всего вы задаете текст для `obj1.label1Outlet.text` во `viewDidLoad`, либо в InterfaceBuilder'е.
Но эти изменения еще не "подгрузились" после вызовов `alloc.init`.

**UPD**

В SecondViewController добавьте свойство

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *testString;
```

а во ViewController добавьте такой метод

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    SecondViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
    vc.testString = self.label1Outlet.text;
}
```

Таким образом перед переходом на второй контроллер вы сохраните в нем текст из первого контроллера.

А этот текст затем можно установить уже во втором контроллере:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.label2Outlet.text = self.testString;
}
```

Надеюсь я все-таки правильно вас понял.

Comment: Да, я задаю текст для obj1.label1Outlet.text в интерфейс билдере. Если подставляю каконто фиксированую строку, то она отображается. 
Значит obj1.label1Outlet.text равно nil. Как сделать так чтобы изменения подгрузились?
Я хочу всего лишь читать данные с одного представления и выводить их на другое

Comment: Для того чтобы подгрузились данные из InterfaceBuilder'а вам достаточно просто дернуть вьюху

    NSLog(@"%@", obj1.view);

Этого вызова достаточно, но это все же костыль)

Answer (score 0):

[[ViewController alloc] init] выделяет память и инициализирует класс. 
Раз в иницилизации нет ни каких телодвижений с label1Outlet.text, то при запросе 
obj1.label1Outlet.text == nil . Если self.label2Outlet.text=obj1.label1Outlet.text присвоить nil в self.label2Outlet.text то, как ни странно self.label2Outlet.text == nil.

По проще в реализации класса ViewController.m перегрузитье метод init

```
-(id)init{
    self.label2Outlet.text=@"Lololo";
}
```

Должно навести на верные мысли.. ;)

Comment: немного вас не понял

Comment: Скачал Ваш проект. Вы инициализируете контроллер с нуля, без какой либо поддержки View и xib (Storyboard). Конечно же переменные пустые. 
Я передал VK в сигвее на другой контроллер со всеми переменными. Приложил проект обратно. Это как один из многих варинтов решения Вашей задачи. Так же есть Синглтон патерн, а так же делегаты, и прочая береберда... ;)

http://dfiles.ru/files/16ca2rame

Answer (score 0):

Переношу из комментария:
В init-е IBOutlet'ы еще не инициализированы. IBOutlet'ы гарантировано инициализированы во -(void)viewDidLoad.

Попробуйте дописать перед присваиванием [obj1 view]; для принудительной загрузки view в память.

Comment: У меня уже голова кипит. я загружаю view,  но все равно значение null. 
Сейчас скрины лучше выложу

Comment: А сколько у Вас контроллеров в Storyboard? И если один, то какой - ViewController или SecondViewController?

Comment: Два контроллера. ViewController  это первый, SecondViewController второй. И мне просто нужно считать метку с первого контроллера и вывести ее на второй

Comment: А заскриньте еще storyboard?

Comment: Еще одна идея: не пишите [[ViewController alloc] init];, а пишите [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

Comment: http://s2.ipicture.ru/uploads/20130506/pxIiLR9X.png
В интерфейсе, там где надпись Denis - это и есть первая метка.

Comment: отредактировала ответ. попробуйте  [obj1 view] вместо [obj1 loadView].

Comment: Вот сам проект http://dfiles.ru/files/e74ppu5ex